# How to use famo.us with loopback framework

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs, famo.us

I want to create a puzzle game using famo.us in my website. This website is build in Angular loopback framework. 
I want to integrate the famous/angular framework in my website, but famous run on different server and loopback is run on different server.

How I can merger both ?

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/Famous/famous-angular?

Answer (score 0):

As s.alem commented, you can use this integration: http://famo.us/integrations/angular.

But take a note that this integration **does not support Mixed mode** (rendering DOM elements and WebGL elements in the same scene) and probably never will, but if you would like to just animate DOM elements inside your application, this integration is good way to go.